# CSS keyframe animations in edge flickers

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe, codepen

I am experimenting with some keyframe animations in css which seem to work fine in IE, Chrome, Firefox but not in Microsoft Edge for some reason. I get this flicker at the end of the animation where I guess it shows their final position and sets the opacity to 1 before hiding them once again and restarting the animation. My code is as follows (This is minified for one bubble, but the link below is a codepen for the whole animation):

HTML:

```
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="bubble"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.canvas { 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bubble {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
}
.bubble:nth-child(1) {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #E6EBF2 0%, #E6EBF2 46%, #EFF0EC 100%);
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  left: 13vw;
  bottom: 52vh;
  -webkit-animation: move1 infinite 10s;
          animation: move1 infinite 10s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 44vh;
    -webkit-transform: translate(10px, 0);
            transform: translate(10px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 44vh;
    -webkit-transform: translate(10px, 0);
            transform: translate(10px, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is a codepen i created:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqqMKe

Any help would be appreciated as I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Hmm it seems that animating anything other than:
    transform: translate()
    transform: scale()
    transform: rotate()
    opacity

Has a high cost factor. I guess i am getting the jitter sometimes because i am animating the bottom property and should probably do this using the existing translate to move it on the Y axis. This does seem to fix the problem i think..